# process a text file with xml column in apache spark scala

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

I have a file like this :

```
1,<note><from>Messi</from><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
2,<note><from>Ronaldo</from><body>Don't forget Laliga</body></note>
3,<note><from>Neymar</from><body>I am the best </body></note>
4,<note><from>Suarez</from><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
```

where first field is id and second field is the data. I need to load this to an RDD, parse the xml string and extract fields, and create another RDD like this:

```
1,Messi,Don't forget me this weekend!
2,Ronaldo,Don't forget Laliga
3,Neymar,I am the best 
4,Suarez,Don't forget me this weekend!
```

Since the xml in actual scenario is complex, I would like to use an xml parser. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Scala's own XML library. But, you will need to parse your string to `Elem` object before you can do that :

```
import scala.xml._

val str = "<note><from>Messi</from><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>"

val xml = XML.loadString(xml)
xml: scala.xml.Elem = <note><from>Messi</from><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
```

To extract a single element, use:

```
xml \\ "note" \\ "from"
res19: scala.xml.NodeSeq = NodeSeq(<from>Messi</from>)
```

This results in an object of type `NodeSeq`, to get the string, use:

```
(xml \\ "note" \\ "from").text
res20: String = Messi
```

Coming to your question

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(
(1,"<note><from>Messi</from><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>"),
(2,"<note><from>Ronaldo</from><body>Don't forget La Liga</body></note>"),
(3,"<note><from>Neymar</from><body>I am the best </body></note>"),
(4,"<note><from>Suarez</from><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>")
)) 

rdd.map{ case (id, xml) => 
    (id , 
    (XML.loadString(xml) \\ "note" \\ "from").text , 
    (XML.loadString(xml) \\ "note" \\ "body").text ) 
}.collect.foreach(println)

(1,Messi,Don't forget me this weekend!)
(2,Ronaldo,Don't forget Laliga)
(3,Neymar,I am the best )
(4,Suarez,Don't forget me this weekend!)
```